# Java switch results (needing to print the values)

Tags: java

I cannot figure this out, I have created a switch in Java for a user to enter specific details. I have created a print statement inside the case to print the result that has been entered. What I want to happen is for a separate print statement to display the combined details of the values entered (after say a few loops). Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
***Here is my code***

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Stage3Check {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Setup an exit statement
    boolean quit = false;
    while (!quit){
        System.out.println("Enter one of the following commands:");
        System.out.println("1 - Damage Repair");
        System.out.println("2 - Traffic Infringement");
        System.out.println("3 - Exit Menu");
        int choiceEntry = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        //Create switch
        if (choiceEntry <1){
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid menu command (1-3)");
        }
        else if (choiceEntry >3){
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid menu command (1-3)");
        }
        double damageCost = 0;
        switch (choiceEntry){
        case 1: System.out.print("Enter a description of the damage:"); 
        String damageDetail = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the damage cost:"); 
        damageCost = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        System.out.print("The damage is: " + damageDetail + "\n");
        System.out.print("The damage cost is: " + "$" + damageCost + "\n");
        break;
        case 2: System.out.print("Enter a description of the traffic infringement:"); 
        String trafficDetail = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the traffic infringement cost:");
        double trafficCost = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        break;
        case 3: quit = true; 
        System.out.println("Menu entry has been terminated.");
        break;


        }
        System.out.print("The damage cost is: " + "$" + damageCost + "\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Take a string builder and keep appending to it, if concatenation is what you need

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the option to an arraylist.

`List<String> listOfEntries=new ArrayList<String>(); // Add strings like damage repair,etc
//Or you could try
List<Integer> listOfOptions=new ArrayList<Integer>();// Add option here, like 1,2`

You can add the user chosen options and at any point of time, you can retreive the options chosen by the user and display the values to the user.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1- The print statement should be placed outside the while loop:

```
System.out.print("The damage cost is: " + "$" + damageCost + "\n");
```

2- Declare the `damageCost` variable globally i.e outside the `while` loop.

3- Change the statement:

```
double trafficCost = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

to

```
damageCost = damageCost + Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
//Setup an exit statement
boolean quit = false;
double dCost=0;
double tCost=0;
StringBuilder dDetail= new StringBuilder("The Damage Details are :" );

StringBuilder tDetail= new StringBuilder("The Traffic details are:  " );
while (!quit){
    System.out.println("Enter one of the following commands:");
    System.out.println("1 - Damage Repair");
    System.out.println("2 - Traffic Infringement");
    System.out.println("3 - Exit Menu");
    int choiceEntry = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    //Create switch
    if (choiceEntry <1){
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid menu command (1-3)");
    }
    else if (choiceEntry >3){
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid menu command (1-3)");
    }
    double damageCost = 0;
    switch (choiceEntry){
        case 1: System.out.print("Enter a description of the damage:"); 
                String damageDetail = input.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter the damage cost:"); 
                damageCost = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                System.out.print("The damage is: " + damageDetail + "\n");
                System.out.print("The damage cost is: " + "$" + damageCost + "\n");

                dDetail.append(damageDetail+"\n");
                dCost=dCost+damageCost;
        break;
        case 2: System.out.print("Enter a description of the traffic infringement:"); 
                String trafficDetail = input.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter the traffic infringement cost:");
                double trafficCost = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                tDetail.append( trafficDetail+"\n");
                tCost=tCost+trafficCost;
        break;
        case 3: quit = true; 
                System.out.println("Menu entry has been terminated.");
                System.out.println("the Total traffic cost is "+tCost);
                System.out.println("the Total Damage cost is "+dCost);
                System.out.println(tDetail);
                System.out.println(dDetail);
        break;


    }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuilder to append your data. PFB updated code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stage3Check {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Setup an exit statement
        boolean quit = false;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        outer: while (!quit) {
            System.out.println("Enter one of the following commands:");
            System.out.println("1 - Damage Repair");
            System.out.println("2 - Traffic Infringement");
            System.out.println("3 - Exit Menu");

            int choiceEntry = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
            // Create switch
            if (choiceEntry < 1 || choiceEntry > 3)
                continue outer;

            double damageCost = 0;

            switch (choiceEntry) {
            case 1:
                System.out.print("Enter a description of the damage:");
                String damageDetail = input.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter the damage cost:");
                damageCost = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                sb.append("The damage is: " + damageDetail + "\n");
                sb.append("The damage cost is: " + "$" + damageCost + "\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out
                        .print("Enter a description of the traffic infringement:");
                String trafficDetail = input.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter the traffic infringement cost:");
                double trafficCost = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                sb.append("The traffic infringement is: " + trafficDetail
                        + "\n");
                sb.append("The traffic infringement cost is: " + "$"
                        + trafficCost + "\n");
                break;
            default:
                quit = true;
                System.out.println("Menu entry has been terminated.");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```